# Using FFmpeg concat filter instead of protocol, differrent results

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have two files that need to be merged.

I can do this using the ffmpeg concat protocol

creating a text file and setting the files in there.

Like so:

***files_to_be_merged.txt***

```
file '/home/user/Videos/video1.mov'
file '/home/user/Videos/video2.mov'
```

and them using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mov
```

But I want to do that without having to create a text file.

I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:video1.mov|video2.mov' -codec copy output.mov
```

But the resulting file is just the first video, not both together.

I get this warning while doing this command;

> [mov @ 0x35933c0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but
> container format requires global headers
>
> [mov @ 0x35933c0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but
> container format requires global headers

Answer (score 0):

The two methods are different.

The one which uses the text file (`-f concat`) is the **concat demuxer** which is more flexible. It works if you have the same codecs but accepts different containers and more importantly works with *any* container format.

The second one (`-i 'concat:file1|file2'`) is the **concat protocol**. It only works for formats that can be directly concatenated such as `mpg` or `mpegts`.

The `mov` format cannot be directly concatenated, so you *must* pass by the demuxer.

See the [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) for more info.

If you don't want to use a text file you can just extend the [existing demuxer](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c2f861ca42fa1a2fb6f7e85abb7bd44f39c6f2c4/libavformat/concatdec.c) to add the functionality. It's an open-source project after all.